# trackchange and citations

Tags: citing, characters, changes

Trackchange for latex on sourceforge seems to have a problem with citations.

```
\change{text 1 \cite{Fels\_81}pad1}{text2 \cite{Fels\_81} pad2}
```

creates a problem due to the brackets encountered. Is there a work around to this?

Comment: It would be best to provide a full minimal example, so that we know for example where `\change` comes from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try enclosing the `\cite` commands inside curly braces:

```
\change{text 1 {\cite{Fels\_81}}pad1}{text2 {\cite{Fels\_81}} pad2}
```

I would suggest you not to use underscores in the argument of `\cite`. I would use something like `Fels-81` instead of `Fels\_81`; the latter produced some errors in the example I built to test the problem; of course, you'll have to change the keys used in your bibliographical entries accordingly.

Comment: Yes, definitive try to avoid `_` in the cite key.