# How do you use trackchanges with a citation in a journal template

Tags: citing, document-classes, trackchanges

Since I originally posted this, I learned that trackchanges has a known bug in dealing with citations. Some workarounds are given at

[workarounds](https://sourceforge.net/p/trackchanges/bugs/12/)

The one that worked for me was using \protect

I am trying to use [trackchanges](http://trackchanges.sourceforge.net/) to make revisions in a manuscript with a journal template and having trouble with citations. If I use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{trackchanges}
\begin{document}
Remove this reference
\remove{
This is a sentence with a reference
\cite{Ells2013}
Will it be removed?
}
This is the end.
\end{document}
```

I get the error "! Argument of @citex has an extra }." And I get the same error if I use the journal document class. If I add extra brackets as suggested in the [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14327/trackchange-and-citations?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C82.3990) ; i.e. {\cite{Ells2013}}, it runs and compiles successfully. If, however, I use the journal template

```
\documentclass[draft]{agujournal2019}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[inline]{trackchanges}
\begin{document}
Remove this reference
\remove{
This is a sentence with a reference
{\cite{Ells2013}}
Will it be removed?
}
This is the end.
\end{document}
```

I get the error "! Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.

See the soul package documentation for explanation"
Looking at the agujournal2019 class file was way beyond me and I could not understand the [soul package](https://ctan.org/pkg/soul?lang=en) documentation. Does anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: You can [try this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139463/how-to-make-hl-highlighting-to-automatically-place-incompatible-commands-in), worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The answer that worked for me was given in the [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139463/how-to-make-hl-highlighting-to-automatically-place-incompatible-commands-in) that [Zuhaib Ahmed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/283335/zuhaib-ahmed) gave (namely adding `\soulregister\cite7` before `\begin{document}`):

```
\documentclass[draft]{agujournal2019}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[inline]{trackchanges}
\soulregister\cite7

\begin{document}
Remove this reference
\remove{
This is a sentence with a reference
\cite{Ells2013}
Will it be removed?
}
This is the end.
\end{document}
```

It's also mentioned in the [bug description](https://sourceforge.net/p/trackchanges/bugs/12/) for trackchanges.